# How can i transfer all ether from smart contract to an address

Tags: solidity

I want to send all ether from a smart contract to an address but I don't know how to do that. 
Here's my code: 
I want to withdraw all the eth to the Owner address

```
contract Counter {
    uint256 public count;

    address public Owner = 0xCA413Bf88AB23371d8E16248738a0b093b5cB3F0;

    event Increment(uint256 value);

    constructor() public {
        count = 0;
    }

    function getCount() public view returns (uint256 count) {
        return count;
    }

    function increment() public payable {
        require(msg.value >= 340628155250860);
        count += 1;
        emit Increment(count);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This contract can't do that. You'd have to implement a function like

```
function withdraw() public onlyOwner {
payable(msg.sender).transfer(address(this).balance) 
}
```

Comment: Okay but to which address would it transfer it to?

Comment: The function i wrote? to `msg.sender` (which is the one who called the contract). In that case it can only be the owner address else the transaction would revert

Comment: He has no once modifier, @Foxxxey could u tell him how to add one :)

Comment: Oh i didnt read the contract i was assuming it implemented `Ownable.sol`. You dont need it though, just replace `onlyOwner` with `require(msg.sender == Owner)`

Comment: Can i somehow do it automatically when increment() is called?

Comment: Yeah, just add `payable(Owner).transfer(address(this).balance)` at the end of your increment function